# About type hinting in PHP

Tags: php, type-hinting

Could anyone write some code how can i implement type hinting in PHP?
Like i have two classes named Book and BookShelf where Book is depends on BookShelf.
So i can write type hinting code like below:
**Book.php**

```
class Book{
  public $bookName;
  public $bookISBN;
  public function getISBN(){
    return $this->bookISBN;
  }
}
```

**BookShelf.php**

```
class BookShelf{
  public $book;
  function _construct(Book $book){
    $this->book = $book;
  }
}
```

Above code is correct or not?
Before type hinting, will i need to import the book class by use with namespace way?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the latest PHP versions(7 or above) do support type hinting. The above code is correct.

Comment: I think in BookShelf class, i need to include the book class with use keyword but not sure.

Comment: You have to import the book class by require, namespace or class autoload function.